# Pycharm debugger and socketio | RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: flask, socket.io, pycharm, flask-socketio

i am using socketio in my python project.
Execution is normal when running execute with no errors.
But when I want to debug, I get a error heading at `socketio.run(app, port=5689, debug=True,allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True )`

Error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I use socketio and also use the debugger?

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent? Removing them might help. Also check the debugger settings in pycharm to see if greenlet support is turned off.